# Get Google Search Results Numbers

Tags: r, rvest

I want to scrape google search results number [image: search_query] my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=Rvest+google+search+result'
scrape<- read_html(url)
search_result <- html_nodes(scrape, "#result-stats" ) %>% 
  html_text()


search_result
character(0)
```

I try with copying xpath but also didnt succeed:

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=Rvest+google+search+result'
first_page <- read_html(url)
search_result  <- html_nodes(first_page,xpath = "//*[@id="appbar"]") %>% 
  html_text()

Error in xml2::xml_text(x, trim = trim) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Answer (score 0):

A `RSelenium` solution

```
library(RSelenium)
driver = rsDriver(browser = c("chrome"))
remDr = driver[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com/")
# Google search rvest 
webElem = remDr$findElement("css", "[name = 'q']")
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list("rvest", "enter"))

res = remDr$findElement('xpath', '//*[@id="slim_appbar"]/div')
res$getElementText()
[[1]] "About 2,95,000 results (0.39 seconds) "
```